# Working with Materialized View

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view, postgresql-9.4, pgbouncer

I have a materialized view which takes around 57 second to be created and I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.

When I do an insert into a table, a trigger will call a trigger function which will do a `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY view` the trigger fires `after each statement` (insert,update,delete)

What happens is, to do a insert it will take around 57 seconds.

How can I fix this and still use a materialized view?

I had this implemented for a long time, and never had this problem, recently I've added pgbouncer, can it be the cause of this?

Comment: A side question, why do you use materialized views if you refresh it on every insert? Isn't a separate table that you manually update with your triggers enough? You will need update and delete triggers, but if you've already gone down the trigger way..

Answer (score 6):

Generally, refreshing the MV immediately only seems reasonable if write access to underlying tables is a *rare* event. A statement-level trigger is better than a row-level trigger, but may still prove too much for big tables. I would consider a solution that polls the database every n minutes checking for updates. You could have a trigger write to a table with a single row.
[Or you could use `LISTEN` / `NOTIFY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634848/calling-external-program-from-postgresql-trigger/21636434#21636434).

As long as you want to propagate every change (almost) immediately, you may be better off with row-level triggers on insert / update / delete writing to a hand-knit "materialized view" (a table), like [@trygvis suggested](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95214/working-with-materialized-view#comment170843_95214).

Since pgbouncer keeps sessions open, there may be locking issues with uncommitted transactions slowing the process down, but I am merely speculating here. You could run tests in a copy of your database without pgbouncer. Or check for zombi transactions by looking up [`pg_stat_activity`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html).